# I need to collapse a single column using a unique ID which contains duplicates and concatenate strings of text in that column only

Tags: python, pandas

I need to combine strings in the text column for matching IDs with duplicats in the ID column. Column A through Column X will have matching data and I want to preserve that in the new dataframe.

| ID | Text | column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | five | 22 |
| 1 | banana | five | 22 |
| 2 | pancake | three | 8 |
| 3 | peach | two | 5 |
| 3 | mango | two | 5 |

I tried this: aggregate(Text ~ ID, data = df, toString)

I am expecting

| ID | text | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple, banana | five | 22 |
| 2 | pancake | three | 8 |
| 3 | peach, mango | two | 5 |

Comment: Please check [How to make pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 1, 2, 3, 3], "Text": ["apple", "banana", "pancake", "peach", "mango"], \
                   "column_A": ["five", "five", "three", "two", "two"], "column_B": [22, 22, 8, 5, 5]})

df = df.groupby(["column_A","column_B", "ID"])["Text"].apply(list).reset_index()
```